# Djangoで１つのアプリでsettingsで使い分けたい

Tags: django

この度Djangoでアプリの作成をしているのですが、
クライアントに応じてサブドメインにて運用を考えておりますが、
システム上同じアプリを設置するのも効率が悪いので、以下のような構成を考えております。

<考えている構成>
一つのアプリに対して、複数のsettingsファイルにてサブドメインごとに使い分けを行いたい。

INSTALLED_APPSのアプリの設定をアプリのおいてある場所のパスにすればいいのかと思っていたのですが、なかなか一筋縄にいかずお手上げしました＞＜。

このような設定を運用を行うことは可能なのでしょうか？
また可能である場合、どのような設定が必要になるのでしょうか？

お忙しいところ大変申し訳ございませんが、
ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

記事が2010年と古いので今のDjangoに適用できるかどうか不明ですが、ApacheとWSGIで可能なようです。

[How to run multiple websites from one Django project](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2010/10/19/run-multiple-websites-one-django-project/)

> 単一のDjangoコードベースから2つ以上のWebサイトまたはサイトのサブドメインを実行すると便利な場合があります。プロジェクト内の各Djangoアプリは、異なるドメインのWebサイトにアクセスできますが、すべてのアプリは単一のデータベースを単一の管理インターフェースで共有できます。
>
> これを実現するには、各Webサイトに個別のWSGIソケットを準備する必要があります。各Webサイトに個別の`settings.py`ファイルを提供して、そのサイトでどのアプリをアクティブにするか、どの`urls.py`ファイルを`ROOT_URLCONF`にするかを選択し、そのドメインへのリクエストのルーティングを処理できます。
>
> この例では、WebFactionホスティングサービスで実行されている1つのサイトの2つのサブドメインをセットアップする方法を示します。

以下、こんな項目の説明があります。詳細はリンク先を参照してください。

> **準備**
>
> **Apacheの構成**
>
> **WSGIスタートアップファイル**
>
> **settings.pyファイル**
>
> **urls.pyファイル**
>
> **結論**